# Match lines with same repeated digit, next to each other or with a space in between

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Using `grep` command to match only lines which have two or more consecutive occurrences of the same digit, even if separated by a space

This is how I am getting the output:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat test_file5 
1234 4567 7890 0984
4565 5678 8900 0767
1234 5678 9021 7654
4556 7890 9005 4432

-bash-4.2$ grep "\([0-9]\)\\1" test_file5
4565 5678 8900 0767  
4556 7890 9005 4432
```

Expected output:

```
1234 4567 7890 0984
4565 5678 8900 0767
4556 7890 9005 4432
```

Comment: Add an example input and your desired output from that.

Answer (score 2):

You add an option to have zero or more non-digit items in between them:

```
grep -E '([0-9])[^0-9]*\1' test_file5
```

Or, if you want to be more rigid, limit it to between 0 and 1 spaces:

```
grep -E '([0-9])[ ]{0,1}\1' test_file5
```

As @Sndeep pointed out in his comment, the single question mark also stands for "the previous might be there or not", so you can also type

```
grep -E '([0-9]) ?\1' test_file5
```

Comment: can also use `?` instead of `{0,1}`